# Sympy : Sensitivity analysis

Tags: sympy

I'm new to Sympy so apologies in advance if I'm asking a simple question.

Let's assume we have an equation z=x*y^2

```
from sympy import *
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
z = x * y**2
```

Now let's say I want to compare 2 cases that are governed by this equation, by only changing one variable.

```
z1 = x1 * y^2   ---(1)   
z2 = x2 * y^2   ---(2)
```

Is there a way in Sympy that I can devide (1) by (2) ,for example giving me the result

```
z1/z2 = x1/x2
```

Ideally, what I want to find out is the sensitivity of this equation for a given parameter without retyping the whole set of equations over and over again.

Comment: Have you looked at [**SALib**](https://salib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?  It is pretty useful to perform a variety of sensitivity analyses.  If I have time, I will post a solution to this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one route you could take:

- `subs(var, expr)` [substitutes](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) one variable for an expression. -
- `expr.simplify()` [simplifies](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) an expression.

The example could look like:

```py
from sympy import symbols

x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2')
z = x * y**2
div = z.subs(x, x1) / z.subs(x, x2)
print(div.simplify())
```

Output:

```
x1/x2
```

In this case `simplify()` isn't strictly necessary, as the immediate simplification already gives `x1/x2`.  Note that there are many variations on `simplify`, such as `expand`, `factor` and `cancel` which each give a different interpretation to simplifying.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the [**Python SALib**](https://salib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to perform sensitivity analysis.  In my example, I am performing a sensitivity analysis.  This does not use SymPy but allows for rigorous sensitivity analysis for any complicated function.  This example should be amenable to adaptation with SymPy.

I did the following example through the Google Colab notebook environment.

This example assumes that you have installed the **SALib**.

```
! pip install salib

import numpy as np
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol



def z(x):
  #column 0 is x and column 1 is y
  return x[:,0]*x[:,1]**2

xMax=10; #change this to suit your needs
yMax = 10; #change this to suit your needs

problem = {'num_vars': 2,
           'names': ['x', 'y'],
            'bounds': [[0, xMax],
                       [0, yMax]]}
# Generate samples
nSamples = 5000; #typically a large number of samples are required (think 100,000)
param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, nSamples, calc_second_order=True)

# Run model
Y = z(param_values)

# Perform analysis
Si = sobol.analyze(problem, Y,calc_second_order=True)
print('First order sensitivity of y with respect to z and b:', Si['S1'], 'respectively.')
print('Second order sensitivity of y with respect to z and b:', Si['S2'], 'respectively.')
```

Other resources that you may find useful:

1. [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkR_lz5OptU) by authors of the SALib.
2. http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/ishigami.html
3. https://risk-engineering.org/notebook/sensitivity-analysis.html

Comment: Thanks very much. Ill have a further look on this.